# Approval process in email

Tags: email, approval-process

I have requirement as to create approval process which can be approved or rejected via email. I found **Automation Setting** to enable email response in which only salesforce users has adminstrative permission is taken. 
Is there any other way to meet this requirement.Can non registered users able to approve the process or not after the submission.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to `Setup > Workflow & Approvals > Process Automation Settings`
there is a checkbox `Enable Email Approval Response` for 
Enabling email approval response lets users reply to email approval requests by typing **APPROVE** or **REJECT** in the first line and adding comments in the second line.

You may want to go through this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_email_parent.htm&type=0) for more detailed information.

Comment: It shows only salesforce users that too only one has System adminstrative permission. How can we enable email response for non registered salesforce users.